# htlatex converting all occurences of 'ff' and 'fi' to null characters in HTML output

Tags: errors, tex4ht, htlatex

I'm running MiKTeX under Windows 7, trying to compile some LaTeX to HTML using htlatex.

htlatex appears to be converting every instance of 'ff' and 'fi' with a NUL byte in the HTML. Was wondering if anybody had any insight!

Here's the config file I'm using (*some stuff I got on the internet that is probably the whole problem*):

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\Configure{HtmlPar}
{\EndP\Tg<p>}
{\EndP\Tg<p>}
{\HCode{</p>\Hnewline}}
{\HCode{</p>\Hnewline}}
\Configure{emph}{\ifvmode\ShowPar\fi\HCode{<em>}}{\HCode{</em>}}
\Configure{textbf}{\ifvmode\ShowPar\fi\HCode{<b>}}{\HCode{</b>}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

And here is an example tex file that illustrates my problem:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\section{Letters}
\subsection{Valid Letters}
AA Aa aA aa\\
BB Bb bB bb\\
CD Cd cD cd\\
\subsection{Invalid Letters}
FF Ff fF ff\\
FI Fi fI fi\\

\section{Strings}
a string of text\\
a fine string of text\\
a definition of an efficient and fine string of text\\
finally, the problem is solved!\\

\end{document}
```

And here is output I get after running the the command

`htlatex example.tex MyFonts.cfg "xhtml, NoFonts, -css" -utf8 -shell-escape`

> 1 Letters
>
> 1.1 Valid Letters
>
> AA Aa aA aa
>   BB Bb bB bb
>   CD Cd cD cd
>
> 1.2 Invalid Letters
>
> FF Ff fF
>   FI Fi fI
>
> 2 Strings
>
> a string of text
>   a ne string of text
>   a denition of an ecient and ne string of text
>
> nally, the problem is solved!

If I look in the HTML output, all occurences of 'ff' and 'fi' have been replaced by the NUL character. Does anybody know why?

Thanks!

Comment: I saved the first snippet as MyFonts.cfg, but `NoFonts` gives error; if I remove it, I get errors because of `-utf8` and `-shell-escape`.

Comment: The error seems to be caused by the -css argument... but why? Also, you can replicate the error (or I can) with just the following command `htlatex minimal.tex MyFonts.cfg "xhtml, -css"`

Comment: With that command line I get, for instance, `a fine string of text` in the `.html` file.

Comment: hm. For some reason the -css is killing it for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You compile it in a wrong way.

Correct compiling order is:

```
htlatex filename "tex4ht.sty opt" "tex4ht command opt" "t4ht command opt" "latex opt"
```

in your case this means this command:

```
htlatex filename "MyFonts, NoFonts, -css" " -utf8" "" -shell-escape
```

this generates fine html for me.

some further notes:

you request `-utf8` option for `tex4ht` command, but you doesn't provide option for unicode fonts `-cunihtf` or `-cmozhtf`, so generated html is in `latin-1` encoding. correct compile sequence for unicode is:

```
htlatex filename "MyFonts,  NoFonts, -css, charset=utf-8" " -utf8 -cunihtf" "" -shell-escape
```

note that in this case ligatures are transformed to unicode characters, which maybe isn't what you want. you can simplify the process with my [make4ht](https://github.com/michal-h21/make4ht) tool:

you can move options for `tex4ht.sty` to the `cfg` file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml,NoFonts, -css}
```

so you don't need to specify them on the command line. Now you can simply call:

```
make4ht -u -c MyFonts -s filename
```

also note that `NoFonts` option may be dangerous - if you add to your tex file:

```
\textbf{příliš} \emph{žluťoučký} \textit{ďábelské}
```

and

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

generated html looks like:

```
<b>Hello příliš</b> <em>žluťoučký</em> ďábelské
```

you can see that there are html tags for `\textbf` and `\emph`, because you provided configuration for these commands, but `\textit` doesn't produce any markup. If you remove `NoFonts` option, due to bug in `tex4ht` command, lot of unnecessary elements around accented characters are produced, which is probably reason why you use `NoFonts`. To fix this issue, you can configure `\textbf` and `\emph` to turn html fonts off:

```
\Configure{emph}{\ifvmode\ShowPar\fi\HCode{<em>}\NoFonts}{\EndNoFonts\HCode{</em>}}
\Configure{textbf}{\ifvmode\ShowPar\fi\HCode{<b>}\NoFonts}{\EndNoFonts\HCode{</b>}}
```

but if you don't want to provide such configurations for all font changing commands, you can use `make4ht` filters. create make file `filename.mk4`:

```
local filter = require "make4ht-filter"
local process = filter{"cleanspan", "fixligatures", "hruletohr"}
Make:htlatex()
Make:htlatex()
Make:match("html$",process)
```

three filters are used in this sample:

- cleanspan removes spurious span elements around accented letters
- fixligatures replaces ligatures with base characters
- hruletohr replaces series of `-----` characters with `<hr />` element

if you remove the `NoFonts` option, generated html is now:

```
<b>příliš</b> <em>žluťoučký</em> <span class="cmti-10">ďábelské </span>
```

so even if `\textit` doesn't produce semantically meaningful code, the text is italicized thanks of css.

Comment: Here (make4ht from TeXlive 20190410 as shipped by Fedora 32) the "fixligatures" doesn'f xix anything, ligatures get translated into NUL characters

Comment: @vonbrand do you get NUL characters for the OP's example? It works for me in TL 2020. If you get NUL characters, it probably means some issue in font mapping. It can happen for some font combinations.