# htlatex converting ligatures to null bytes

Tags: html, libertine, htlatex

I am familiar with questions [162626](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162626/htlatex-converting-all-occurences-of-ff-and-fi-to-null-characters-in-html-ou) and with [204822](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204822/document-with-string-having-ff-and-fi-converting-to-null-or-empty-characters), and have followed the instructions therein, but have been unable to get a good solution.  htlatex is converting all of the ligatures in a document into null bytes.  MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[oldstyle,proportional]{libertine}
\begin{document}
find the fly; it's difficult, but fluffy.
\end{document}
```

My command line:

```
htlatex test.tex "xhtml, -css, charset=utf-8" " -utf8 -cunihtf" "" -shell-escape;
```

The problem seems to be in `libertine`; when I don't load it, the ligatures come out fine, but when I do, the ligatures are null.  This suggests the solution of simply removing the `libertine` package and then compiling with `htlatex`, but I'd really like to avoid having to modify my document in order to convert it to HTML.

Does anyone have a suggested solution to this?

Comment: Maybe http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5153/is-there-an-iftex4ht-command-and-if-not-how-should-it-be-defined can help you?

Comment: Sure, it helps; but I still have to modify my document.  The idea here is that I'd be able to write my document without having to worry about the eventual conversion to HTML.  It might not be possible; but if it is, I know somebody here will know it.

Comment: Well, you would only have to change your document at one place in the preamble, and afterwards it would work fine for pdf and for HTML.  The alternative is to change libertine.sty.  It would suffice to put a patched version of libertine.sty in the folder of your tex file.  You could try to use the answers from the same question (5153) to make libertine.sty check whether htlatex is running.

Comment: Well, as the documentation says, "It is highly recommended to leave source LaTeX and TeX files intact, and not introduce TeX4ht configurations there."  I'm trying to go with that.  Your suggestion is a good one, as it at least saves me from having to maintain a separate copy of the document without `libertine` loaded.  But something config-file wise seems better to me, if there is anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is still no full support for Linux Libertine in `tex4ht`, as there are literally dozens fonts for various font encodings, styles, sizes and weights. But, it is not that hard to add support for basic T1 fonts, using [htfgen](https://github.com/michal-h21/htfgen).

You can find that some font support is missing from `tex4ht` command output:

```
tex4ht test.dvi " -cunihtf -utf8"
```

this will print really lot of text, because it prints contents of `tex4ht.env` file, which isn't exactly small. But at the beginning, you can find this:

```
tex4ht.c (2012-07-25-19:36 kpathsea)
tex4ht sample.dvi 
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex4ht/base/unix/tex4ht.env)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex4ht/ht-fonts/iso8859/1/html/charset/unicode.4hf)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinLibertineTB-osf-t1.tfm)
(LinLibertineTB-osf-t1.htf)
Searching `LinLibertineT-osf-t1.htf' for `LinLibertineTB-osf-t1.htf'
--- warning --- Couldn't find font `LinLibertineT-osf-t1.htf' (char codes: 0--255)

----------------------------------------------------
environment file
----------------------------------------------------
% tex4ht.env-unix (2015-02-15-10:26), generated from tex4ht-env.tex
```

so, we need to create file `LinLibertineT-osf-t1.htf`, which corresponds to `LinLibertineT-osf-t1.tfm`. We can inspect used font encoding and whether the font is virtual or real with `lstexenc` command provided by  `htfgen` project:

```
$ lstexenc LinLibertineT-osf-t1
LinLibertineT-osf-t1    vf      EXTENDED TEX FONT ENCODING - LATIN
  LinLibertineT-osf-t1--base    tfm     EXTENDED TEX FONT ENCODING - LATIN
```

so we see that it is virtual font and it uses some non-standard font encoding. It uses `LinLibertineT-osf-t1--base` as a base font, sometimes virtual fonts contains several fonts, so this isn't that bad.

Exact font encoding can be sometimes found in the `.map` file. Easiest way to find is to search with Google for `fontname enc`, so `LinLibertineT-osf-t1--base enc` in our case (yes, the enc file is provided for the base fonts. If the virtual font contain several real fonts, we need to find encodings for each one). The search finds file `libertine.map`, which provides encodings for all Libertine real fonts. We have to search it for `LinLibertineT-osf-t1--base`:

```
LinLibertineT-osf-t1--base LinLibertineT "AutoEnc_ulngvdga3jyvcsz3zod63p4gna ReEncodeFont" <[lbtn_ulngvd.enc <LinLibertineT.pfb
```

important is `<[lbtn_ulngvd.enc` part, which contains the encoding name, `lbtn_ulngvd`. Now we can create helper table for `LinLibertineT-osf-t1`:

```
tfmtochars LinLibertineT-osf-t1 lbtn_ulngvd > LinLibertineT-osf-t1.tsv
```

and finally to create the `.htf` file:

```
htfgen LinLibertineT-osf-t1.tsv > LinLibertineT-osf-t1.htf
```

the result is following:

```
LinLibertineT-osf-t1 0 255
'&#x0060;'  ''  grave
'&#x00B4;'  ''  acute
'&#x02C6;'  ''  circumflex
'&#x02DC;'  ''  tilde
'&#x00A8;'  ''  dieresis
'&#x02DD;'  ''  hungarumlaut
'&#x02DA;'  ''  ring
'&#x02C7;'  ''  caron
'&#x02D8;'  ''  breve
'&#x00AF;'  ''  macron
'&#x02D9;'  ''  dotaccent
'&#x00B8;'  ''  cedilla
'&#x02DB;'  ''  ogonek
'&#x201A;'  ''  quotesinglbase
'&#x2039;'  ''  guilsinglleft
'&#x203A;'  ''  guilsinglright
'&#x201C;'  ''  quotedblleft
'&#x201D;'  ''  quotedblright
'&#x201E;'  ''  quotedblbase
'&#x00AB;'  ''  guillemotleft
'&#x00BB;'  ''  guillemotright
'&#x2013;'  ''  endash
'&#x2014;'  ''  emdash
'&#xnil;'   ''  .notdef
'&#x2080;'  ''  perthousandzero
'&#x0131;'  ''  dotlessi
'&#x0237;'  ''  dotlessj
'&#xFB01;'  ''  f_i
'&#xFB03;'  ''  f_f_i
'&#xFB00;'  ''  f_f
'&#xFB02;'  ''  f_l
'&#xFB04;'  ''  f_f_l
'&#x2423;'  ''  uni2423
'&#x0021;'  ''  exclam
'&#x0022;'  ''  quotedbl
'&#x0023;'  ''  numbersign
'&#x0024;'  ''  dollar
'&#x0025;'  ''  percent
'&#x0026;'  ''  ampersand
'&#x2019;'  ''  quoteright
'&#x0028;'  ''  parenleft
'&#x0029;'  ''  parenright
'&#x002A;'  ''  asterisk
'&#x002B;'  ''  plus
'&#x002C;'  ''  comma
'&#x002D;'  ''  hyphen
'&#x002E;'  ''  period
'&#x002F;'  ''  slash
'&#xF730;'  ''  zero.oldstyle
'&#xF731;'  ''  one.oldstyle
'&#xF732;'  ''  two.oldstyle
'&#xF733;'  ''  three.oldstyle
'&#xF734;'  ''  four.oldstyle
'&#xF735;'  ''  five.oldstyle
'&#xF736;'  ''  six.oldstyle
'&#xF737;'  ''  seven.oldstyle
'&#xF64B;'  ''  eight.taboldstyle
'&#xF739;'  ''  nine.oldstyle
'&#x003A;'  ''  colon
'&#x003B;'  ''  semicolon
'&#x003C;'  ''  less
'&#x003D;'  ''  equal
'&#x003E;'  ''  greater
'&#x003F;'  ''  question
'&#x0040;'  ''  at
'&#x0041;'  ''  A
'&#x0042;'  ''  B
'&#x0043;'  ''  C
'&#x0044;'  ''  D
'&#x0045;'  ''  E
'&#x0046;'  ''  F
'&#x0047;'  ''  G
'&#x0048;'  ''  H
'&#x0049;'  ''  I
'&#x004A;'  ''  J
'&#x004B;'  ''  K
'&#x004C;'  ''  L
'&#x004D;'  ''  M
'&#x004E;'  ''  N
'&#x004F;'  ''  O
'&#x0050;'  ''  P
'&#x0051;'  ''  Q
'&#x0052;'  ''  R
'&#x0053;'  ''  S
'&#x0054;'  ''  T
'&#x0055;'  ''  U
'&#x0056;'  ''  V
'&#x0057;'  ''  W
'&#x0058;'  ''  X
'&#x0059;'  ''  Y
'&#x005A;'  ''  Z
'&#x005B;'  ''  bracketleft
'&#x005C;'  ''  backslash
'&#x005D;'  ''  bracketright
'&#x005E;'  ''  asciicircum
'&#x005F;'  ''  underscore
'&#x2018;'  ''  quoteleft
'&#x0061;'  ''  a
'&#x0062;'  ''  b
'&#x0063;'  ''  c
'&#x0064;'  ''  d
'&#x0065;'  ''  e
'&#x0066;'  ''  f
'&#x0067;'  ''  g
'&#x0068;'  ''  h
'&#x0069;'  ''  i
'&#x006A;'  ''  j
'&#x006B;'  ''  k
'&#x006C;'  ''  l
'&#x006D;'  ''  m
'&#x006E;'  ''  n
'&#x006F;'  ''  o
'&#x0070;'  ''  p
'&#x0071;'  ''  q
'&#x0072;'  ''  r
'&#x0073;'  ''  s
'&#x0074;'  ''  t
'&#x0075;'  ''  u
'&#x0076;'  ''  v
'&#x0077;'  ''  w
'&#x0078;'  ''  x
'&#x0079;'  ''  y
'&#x007A;'  ''  z
'&#x007B;'  ''  braceleft
'&#x007C;'  ''  bar
'&#x007D;'  ''  braceright
'&#x007E;'  ''  asciitilde
'&#x002D;'  ''  hyphen
'&#x0102;'  ''  Abreve
'&#x0104;'  ''  Aogonek
'&#x0106;'  ''  Cacute
'&#x010C;'  ''  Ccaron
'&#x010E;'  ''  Dcaron
'&#x011A;'  ''  Ecaron
'&#x0118;'  ''  Eogonek
'&#x011E;'  ''  Gbreve
'&#x0139;'  ''  Lacute
'&#x013D;'  ''  Lcaron
'&#x0141;'  ''  Lslash
'&#x0143;'  ''  Nacute
'&#x0147;'  ''  Ncaron
'&#x014A;'  ''  Eng
'&#x0150;'  ''  Ohungarumlaut
'&#x0154;'  ''  Racute
'&#x0158;'  ''  Rcaron
'&#x015A;'  ''  Sacute
'&#x0160;'  ''  Scaron
'&#x015E;'  ''  Scedilla
'&#x0164;'  ''  Tcaron
'&#x0162;'  ''  Tcedilla
'&#x0170;'  ''  Uhungarumlaut
'&#x016E;'  ''  Uring
'&#x0178;'  ''  Ydieresis
'&#x0179;'  ''  Zacute
'&#x017D;'  ''  Zcaron
'&#x017B;'  ''  Zdotaccent
'&#x0132;'  ''  IJ
'&#x0130;'  ''  Idotaccent
'&#x0111;'  ''  dcroat
'&#x00A7;'  ''  section
'&#x0103;'  ''  abreve
'&#x0105;'  ''  aogonek
'&#x0107;'  ''  cacute
'&#x010D;'  ''  ccaron
'&#x010F;'  ''  dcaron
'&#x011B;'  ''  ecaron
'&#x0119;'  ''  eogonek
'&#x011F;'  ''  gbreve
'&#x013A;'  ''  lacute
'&#x013E;'  ''  lcaron
'&#x0142;'  ''  lslash
'&#x0144;'  ''  nacute
'&#x0148;'  ''  ncaron
'&#x014B;'  ''  eng
'&#x0151;'  ''  ohungarumlaut
'&#x0155;'  ''  racute
'&#x0159;'  ''  rcaron
'&#x015B;'  ''  sacute
'&#x0161;'  ''  scaron
'&#x015F;'  ''  scedilla
'&#x0165;'  ''  tcaron
'&#x0163;'  ''  tcedilla
'&#x0171;'  ''  uhungarumlaut
'&#x016F;'  ''  uring
'&#x00FF;'  ''  ydieresis
'&#x017A;'  ''  zacute
'&#x017E;'  ''  zcaron
'&#x017C;'  ''  zdotaccent
'&#x0133;'  ''  ij
'&#x00A1;'  ''  exclamdown
'&#x00BF;'  ''  questiondown
'&#x00A3;'  ''  sterling
'&#x00C0;'  ''  Agrave
'&#x00C1;'  ''  Aacute
'&#x00C2;'  ''  Acircumflex
'&#x00C3;'  ''  Atilde
'&#x00C4;'  ''  Adieresis
'&#x00C5;'  ''  Aring
'&#x00C6;'  ''  AE
'&#x00C7;'  ''  Ccedilla
'&#x00C8;'  ''  Egrave
'&#x00C9;'  ''  Eacute
'&#x00CA;'  ''  Ecircumflex
'&#x00CB;'  ''  Edieresis
'&#x00CC;'  ''  Igrave
'&#x00CD;'  ''  Iacute
'&#x00CE;'  ''  Icircumflex
'&#x00CF;'  ''  Idieresis
'&#x00D0;'  ''  Eth
'&#x00D1;'  ''  Ntilde
'&#x00D2;'  ''  Ograve
'&#x00D3;'  ''  Oacute
'&#x00D4;'  ''  Ocircumflex
'&#x00D5;'  ''  Otilde
'&#x00D6;'  ''  Odieresis
'&#x0152;'  ''  OE
'&#x00D8;'  ''  Oslash
'&#x00D9;'  ''  Ugrave
'&#x00DA;'  ''  Uacute
'&#x00DB;'  ''  Ucircumflex
'&#x00DC;'  ''  Udieresis
'&#x00DD;'  ''  Yacute
'&#x00DE;'  ''  Thorn
'&#xnil;'   ''  .notdef
'&#x00E0;'  ''  agrave
'&#x00E1;'  ''  aacute
'&#x00E2;'  ''  acircumflex
'&#x00E3;'  ''  atilde
'&#x00E4;'  ''  adieresis
'&#x00E5;'  ''  aring
'&#x00E6;'  ''  ae
'&#x00E7;'  ''  ccedilla
'&#x00E8;'  ''  egrave
'&#x00E9;'  ''  eacute
'&#x00EA;'  ''  ecircumflex
'&#x00EB;'  ''  edieresis
'&#x00EC;'  ''  igrave
'&#x00ED;'  ''  iacute
'&#x00EE;'  ''  icircumflex
'&#x00EF;'  ''  idieresis
'&#x00F0;'  ''  eth
'&#x00F1;'  ''  ntilde
'&#x00F2;'  ''  ograve
'&#x00F3;'  ''  oacute
'&#x00F4;'  ''  ocircumflex
'&#x00F5;'  ''  otilde
'&#x00F6;'  ''  odieresis
'&#x0153;'  ''  oe
'&#x00F8;'  ''  oslash
'&#x00F9;'  ''  ugrave
'&#x00FA;'  ''  uacute
'&#x00FB;'  ''  ucircumflex
'&#x00FC;'  ''  udieresis
'&#x00FD;'  ''  yacute
'&#x00FE;'  ''  thorn
'&#x00DF;'  ''  germandbls
LinLibertineT-osf-t1 0 255
```

(you need to add blank line at the end of the file, Stack Exchange eats is)

We should also add support for bold and italics. We don't have to repeat the whole process if the fonts use the same encoding. Unfortunately, each font use different encoding, but after diff it doesn't seem that they differ substantially, so we can just create `.htf` files, which doesn't include all unicode values for all characters, but just link to `LinLibertineT-osf-t1`. This second type of the `htf` file looks like this:

LinLibertineTB-osf-t1.htf:

```
.LinLibertineT-osf-t1
htfcss:  LinLibertineTB-osf-t1  font-weight: bold; font-family: "Linux Libertine O",serif;
```

LinLibertineTI-osf-t1:

```
.LinLibertineT-osf-t1
htfcss:  LinLibertineTI-osf-t1  font-weight: normal; font-style: italic; font-family: "Linux Libertine O",serif;
```

If you haven't disabled the `CSS`, you would see something like:

[image]

As you can see, the normal font isn't styled, but bold and italics are. You can fix it with simple config file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\Css{body{font-family: "Linux Libertine O", serif;}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

Also note that unicode old-style numbers are used instead of normal ones. Final result:

[image]